# TYPO3: Can't find the Ajax Route

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, routes, typo3

I did that Tutorial from the TYPO3 Page v11.5:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Backend/Ajax.html

First of all my Extention Tree:

```
├── Classes
│   └── Controller
│       └── ExampleController.php
├── Configuration
│   ├── Backend
│   │   └── AjaxRoutes.php
│   └── Services.yaml
├── Resources
│   ├── Private
│   │   └── Templates
│   │       └── test.html
│   └── Public
│       └── JavaScript
│           └── Calculate.js
├── composer.json
├── ext_emconf.php
└── ext_localconf.php
```

My AjaxRoutes:

```
<?php
use (privacy)\ajaxcool\Controller\ExampleController;

return [
    'myextension_example_dosomething' => [
        'path' => '/ajaxcool/do-something',
        'target' => ExampleController::class . '::doSomethingAction',
    ],
];
```

My ext_localconf.php

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['ajaxRoutes']['myextension_example_dosomething'] = [
    'path' => '/ajaxcool/do-something',
    'target' =>
(privacy)\ajaxcool\Controller\ExampleController::class . '::doSomethingAction',
];
```

In the bottom of this TYPO3 Tutorial Page is a JS Tutorial there i get an Error because i cant use require in the frontend. So i thought i can use `fetch` so i wrote that Script:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://ajax-typo3-test3.ddev.site/';
const inputNumber = 5;
fetch(`${baseUrl}/ajaxcool/do-something?input=${inputNumber}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

That didn't work.
`Calculate.js:29 Error: Error: Network response was not ok`

I thought i can just use my Browser and check if i can find that Url.

`https://ajax-typo3-test3.ddev.site/ajaxcool/do-something?input=5`

Error:

```
404
Page Not Found
The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: The requested page does not exist
```

I hope u know what i did wrong and that you can Help me, Thanks!

Comment: You are checking with Backend, but check it here (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Ajax/ClientSide/Index.html) for frontend

Comment: The tutorial is about backend, so the prefix in the URL would be /typo3/ajaxcool/dosomething.
When you want a route for frontend, you can use, for example, a middleware: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html